# Braid 2-groups, symmetric 2-groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, ct.category-theory, symmetric-groups, braid-groups, higher-algebra

Is there an object which can be called a "braid 2-group"? Or a "symmetric 2-group"? (Note: not a *braided* 2-group)
I am ignorant about 2-categories but I hope that a good candidate for the
braid 2-group should be related to the Zamolodchikov's tetrahedron equation.

Comment: You might be interested in the work of Epa and Ganter on Platonic 2-groups. I believe there should be 2-group analogues of the alternating groups, further extending the extension of $A_n$ by its Schur multiplier, but I've not seen work on this.

Comment: Every category $C$ has a 2-group of auto-equivalences, which I think could be called the symmetric 2-group of $C$. The 2-categorical point of view helps: it is the automorphism 2-group of the object $C$ in the 2-category of categories.

Comment: The $n$th braid group is defined to be $\pi_1(\mathrm{UConf}_n(\mathbb{R}^2))$, and since $\mathrm{UConf}_n(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is path-connected, we can identify it with the fundamental groupoid $\Pi_{\leq 1}(\mathrm{UConf}_n(\mathbb{R}^2))$ of $\mathrm{UConf}_n(\mathbb{R}^2)$. From this point of view, the "higher braid $k$-groups" should then have the form $\Pi_{\leq k}(\mathrm{UConf}_n(\mathbb{R}^m))$. These are indeed related to the Zamolodchikov tetrahedron equation, as the latter appear crucially...

Comment: ...in the theory of braided monoidal bicategories (see e.g. [this](https://www.math.ias.edu/vladimir/sites/math.ias.edu.vladimir/files/1994_Kapranov_Voevodsky.pdf#page=64)), and indeed $\Pi_{\leq 2}(\mathrm{UConf}_n(\mathbb{R}^2))$ is the free braided monoidal bicategory, as proved in [arXiv:1102.0981](https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.0981) (see in particular the introduction; there's quite a bit about higher-dimensional braids there!).

Comment: $\newcommand{\a}{\mathrm{UConf}_n(\mathbb{R}^\infty)}$The same point of view applies also to the symmetric group, but things are less interesting: $\Sigma_n$ is isomorphic to $\pi_1(\a)$, and for the same reason as above we can identify this with $\Pi_{\leq1}(\a)$. Now however we can't replace $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ with anything higher-dimensional, and also there is no value in considering higher fundamental groupoids of $\a)$, as $\pi_k(\a)\cong0$ for $k\geq2$. Thus (at least from this point of view) the "$n$th symmetric $2$-group" is just the discrete monoidal category on $\Sigma_n$ :/

Comment: (An "answer" that is I think quite different from what you are looking for but is nevertheless interesting is the following: the braid category $\mathbb{B}=\coprod_{n=0}^\infty\mathbf{B}\mathrm{B}_n$ is the free braided monoidal category on the punctual category $\mathsf{pt}$, while the groupoid of finite sets and permutations $\mathbb{F}=\coprod_{n=0}^\infty\mathbf{B}\Sigma_n$ is the free *symmetric* monoidal category on $\mathsf{pt}$. The $2$-group completion of the former is the fundamental groupoid $\Pi_{\leq1}\Omega^2S^2$ of $\Omega^2S^2$, which...

Comment: ...admits the explicit description given [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403448). Meanwhile, the $2$-group completion of $\mathbb{F}$ is $\Pi_{\leq1}\Omega^\infty\mathbb{S}$, the fundamental groupoid of the (underlying $\mathbb{E}_\infty$-space of the) sphere spectrum, which may be described as in [Section 3 here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.2686.pdf#page=8). Thus in a sense we can start with the braid (resp. symmetric) groups, build a monoidal category from them, and then $2$-group complete the result to get a $2$-group.)